# Problems connecting to postgre with python (in pg_hba.conf)

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to connect to a Postgres database from a Jupyter Notebook using the psycopg2 library.
First of all, I installed it:

```
conda install psycopg2
```

Looks fine. Next step was try to connect to by database in cloud:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(#my_database_credentials)
```

And I got error like:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host...
```

I am starting to find this file, and found two on my computer. One in /UserName/Anaconda3/Library/share and one in /UserName/Anaconda3/libpq-11.2-h3235a2c_0/Library/Share
So, I changed both files in several different ways, for example:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD
local   all       all            trust
host    all       all   all      trust
```

But I still got the same error. So my question is:
What else do I need to install? Or maybe I need to configure other files? Or what I need to do to connect to the database. Thank you

Comment: first of all connection string normally follows the format: 
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'"
are you using the right format for this?

Comment: Yes, I know about that. I just hide them here

Comment: mostly for conda i have seen folks do this:
conda install -c anaconda psycopg2.
not sure if that is really going to solve your problem.

Comment: @Rerik try to change ADDRESS section in pg_hba.conf to 0.0.0.0/0